# Using Flask API on a Dash webportal

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

I have a webportal that is using Dash. I just want to add a direct API link on this server, for people who can need some data of it.

so here is how I process, I have try 2 way :

```
from flask_restful import Api
server = Flask(__name__)
server.secret_key = os.environ.get('secret_key', 'secret')
app = dash.Dash(__name__,
                server=server,
                external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP],
                suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

@server.route('/test')
def route1():
    return {"test": "success"}

@server.route('/test2/<param>')
def route2(param):
    return {"test": param}

class CreateApi(Resource):
def get(self):
    data = str(request.args['test'])
    return {'hello': data}
api = Api(server)
api.add_resource(CreateApi, '/hello')
```

locally everything good when I test the different link and I get these result :

http://127.0.0.1:8050/test

http://127.0.0.1:8050/test2/ok

http://127.0.0.1:8050/hello?test=test

[image]
[image]
[image]

however, when I deploy the application and try to access these API endpoint I don't get the result of the API, and more, I get some Front End stuff like that (stuff on the left is the main page result, and "Page in development" the default when we try to access an endpoint that does not exist) :

[image]

So I am probably doing the wrong way to try to access the API on my production server, but I don't find any stuff that explain the difference with local development